# GE Profile dishwasher spring adjustment

Tags: appliances, dishwasher

I just purchased a GE Profile dishwasher model #PDT715SYNFS and the door falls open right after opening it. I need to adjust the spring tension but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that. The instructions show moving the spring up or down along the back rail in holes but there are no holes on this model that I can see. Any thoughts? I can't find a video or anything online.

Thanks!

Comment: The holes might be covered with paint

Comment: Provide a picture of your installation.

Comment: I doubt the holes are covered with paint; the rails are typically bare (or at most galvanized).  Did you look at any of the videos showing how to adjust the springs?  Have you tried to take pics of the rails where the holes should be?

Comment: Page 13: https://products-salsify.geappliances.com/image/upload/s--aB2cWxgA--/sgdyhtwlwcmzyfsmuhe0.pdf "Models with tubular frames are not adjustable." Check that the cables are routed through the pulleys correctly.

Comment: Ended up having it replaced, Lowes came and looked at it and they said something was broken as these models are not adjustable.